# Network structure: k-cliques vs. p-cliques

Tags: definitions, social-network-analysis, graphs

In network structure, what is the difference between **k-cliques** and **p-cliques**, can anyone give a brief explaination with examples? Thanks in advanced!

============================

EDIT:
I found an online [ppt](http://open.umich.edu/sites/default/files/SI508-F08-Week7-Lab6.ppt) while I am googling, please take a look on **p.37** and **p.39**, can you comment on them?

Comment: In what context did you see these terms? It seems that `p` and `k` simply show the size of the subgraph, not a special category of them.

Comment: please see the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In graph theory a clique indicates a fully connected set of nodes: [as noted here](http://books.google.com/books?id=E3-OSVSPbU0C&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=%22graph%20theory%22,%20%22p-clique%22&source=bl&ots=smbhcK-9AC&sig=X0v_EbqSqB4WBbudgPbqo_j1pvk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VNWiU8KaA9WxsQSQhYGIAg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22graph%20theory%22,%20%22p-clique%22&f=false), a p-clique simply indicates a clique comoprised of p nodes. A k-clique is an undirected graph and a number k, and the output is a clique of size k if one exists.

[Clique Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem)

Comment: please see the edit

Comment: an n-clique is something else altogether from a k-clique or a p-clique. The n-clique refers to a maximal distance between two subgroups, where a k-clique refers to a clique of size k, where k is some constant chosen, and a p-clique is simply a clique composed of p nodes again where p is a chosen constant